# Java paint image on negative coordinates

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I want to do something best explained by this picture:

[image: image on jpanel]

In words, i need to right-down part of picture into left-top part of jpanel, i have tried setting x and y to negative, but with no succes, the image is just not displayed at all. It there a simple way to do this?

I am currently using

```
g.drawImage(img, x, y, null)
//x and y are negative
```

to draw it.

Comment: I think this Question/Answer could be going into the direction you are looking for.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534946/does-g-drawimage-render-only-the-part-of-the-image-visible-on-a-jpanel-or-doe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would verify you x/y position is being calculated correctly and add a `ImageObserver` reference to your `g.drawImage` if you're painting to the screen

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NegativeImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NegativeImage();
    }

    public NegativeImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/Evil_Small.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- img.getHeight()) / 2;
            // Center...
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);

            // Off to the left...
            x = -(img.getWidth() / 2);
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);

            // Off to the right...
            x = getWidth() - (img.getWidth() / 2);
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        }        
    }    
}
```